# GitHub - Exclude certain repository from collecting contributions which is showed in my profile

Tags: github

I'm using [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-settings-repository.html) to sync my settings between multiple environments. Whenever I open/close my IDE, it automatically sync local data with remote and makes a new commit.

The problem is, in my GitHub profile, those commits are collected as private contributions. So the number of contributions is too high than what I've actually done.

Is there a way to hide or remove contributions from certain repository? Or should I use another git host? (like GitLab)

Comment: Are you getting a commit even  if your settings don’t change?

Comment: Yeah it seems..

Answer (score 2):

There is a Profile Setting whether or not to include commits to private repos in your stats.

[image: settings screenshot]

I don’t know of a per-repo setting.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks for reply. I'm gonna use GitLab for this.